# Avoid trimming of bash $() output

Tags: bash, newline

From the Bash manual:

> Bash performs the expansion by
>   executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard
>   output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines deleted.

That means obscure bugs are possible when handling output with meaningful trailing newlines. A contrived example:

```
user@host:~$ path='test

'
user@host:~$ touch -- "$path"
user@host:~$ readlink -fn -- "$path"
/home/user/test

user@host:~$ full_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$path")"
user@host:~$ ls -- "$full_path"
ls: cannot access /home/user/test: No such file or directory
```

Any tips on how to assign the value of a command to a variable without losing semantically useful data?

The adventures of Bash continue another day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use quoting and `eval` to work around this. Change your last two commands to:

```
full_path="'$(readlink -fn -- "$path"; echo \')"
eval ls -- "$full_path"
```

If you want the result with trailing newlines in a variable you could first add a bogus character (in this case underscore) and then remove that.

```
full_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$path"; echo _)"
full_path=${full_path%_}
ls -- "$full_path"
```

Comment: I need the result to be stored in a variable with the trailing newlines. How would you do that?

Comment: Awesome hack. On a tangential note, I sure hope we get a good object oriented shell in Linux soon. Despite its other flaws, PowerShell had a good model to be able to access object properties.

Comment: @10b0: If you want a non-POSIX shell for Linux you can try zoidberg, which is a Perl shell. Of course you're still dealing with Perl at that point. There are other shells for other languages. The lack of PowerShell-like shells is due to a lack of need and desire, not a technical challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I have no good answers. However, this hack will work for both files with and without newlines in the name.

```
path='test

'
touch -- "$path"
readlink -fn -- "$path"
full_path=
if [[ $path =~ $'\n' ]] ; then
        while IFS=$'\n' read fn ; do
                full_path+="$fn"$'\n'
        done < <(readlink -fn -- "$path")
else
        full_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$path")"
fi
ls -l -- "$full_path"
```

Answer (score 0):

One (deprecated) way could be to use back-quotes instead of $(); try:

```
full_path=`readlink -fn -- $path`
```

Comment: Why exactly would backticks behave differently?

Comment: @Sorpigal: I don't know, I have tried it in my console and it works

Comment: Doesn't work, and grave accents (aka. backticks) are not deprecated - The Bash manual refers to them simply as "old-style".

Answer (score 0):

```
$ readlink -f "$path"
```

This return the good path. I don't know why you used the -n option with readlink because it removes newlines.

Unfortunatly when I store the result of this command the newline seems to be removed

```
$ fullpath=`readlink -f "$path"`
$ echo "$fullpath"
/home/test
```

No newlines. I don't know if it's "echo" or the way to store that remove the newline at the end of the path.

```
$ ls
test?
$ls test?
test?
```

Newline seems to be replaced by ?. May be there is something to do with it.

Comment: `-n` doesn't remove newlines, it avoids appending an *extra* newline after the filename, thus making it useful to get the filename in case it can contain newlines at the end. As on pretty much all *nixes